# Create column of truth values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
    date      people_count
0   30/03/17  6

1   31/03/17  4

2   1/04/17   7

3   2/04/17   9
```

How can you create a new column which indicates if the date is a weekend(**1**), or if the date is a weekday(**0**)?

Something like this:

```
    date      people_count   weekend
0   30/03/17  6              0

1   31/03/17  4              0

2   1/04/17   7              1

3   2/04/17   9              1
```

So far I have created a column which stores the day number(**0-6**), from `DateTimeIndex.dayofweek`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

df['weekend'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).dayofweek
```

But I am unsure of how to evaluate these values and replace them with **1** for weekends, and **0** for weekdays. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weekends are days 5 (Saturday) and 6 (Sunday). So just check what day it's returning.

```
df['weekend'] = [ 1 if day in (5, 6) else 0 for day in pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).dayofweek ]
```

Comment: thanks :), I get this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that I needed to make it an array comprehension for pandas.

Answer (score 2):

First, you may have to specify the date format -- I get

```
In [31]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])
Out[31]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-30', '2017-03-31', '2017-01-04', '2017-02-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

from your input and I don't think that's what you wanted.  Once you have that, though, it's easy to compute, whether as a bool column or an int column, using the `.dt` accessor:

```
In [48]: pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%y")
Out[48]: 
0   2017-03-30
1   2017-03-31
2   2017-04-01
3   2017-04-02
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [49]: (pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%y").dt.weekday >= 5)
Out[49]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: date, dtype: bool

In [50]: (pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%y").dt.weekday >= 5).astype(int)
Out[50]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```